# angular 14 does not install

Tags: javascript, angular, command-line-interface

I had angular 9 installed on my computer and I uninstalled it to install Angular 14, but when I install version 14, it still shows me version 9.

step 1: uninstall angular with npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

step 2: install angular 14 with npm install -g @angular/cli@14.0.0

step 3: clean cache with npm cache clean --force

step 4: check version with ng --version but version 9 continues to appear

[image]

The other option I tried was using the ng update command but it gave me the following error

[image]

Comment: Does the install of angular 14 complete without errors? You can also check the folder where your global packages are installed. Personal opinion: Don't install angular globally, install it on a per project basis. That also makes switching between projects with different angular versions much easier.

Comment: Have you updated NodeJS/NPM globally? Only the latest compatible version of Angular will be installed.

Comment: @cloned How do I install angular per project? It is assumed that when I create a new project I do it with ng new project_name, at that point the project has already been created. I don't understand how I could install a version of Angular per project

Comment: what about your node version have updated that one as well. If not then please do so. might be the problem with node version compatibility issue

Comment: You run `npm install @angular/...` in the project root where you want to install angular. (Same command as before, just without the `-g` flag. You can run angular commands prefixed with `npx`, eg. `npx ng g c...` (to generate a component). And as other said: Make sure your npm version is compatible with angular 14!