# Angular not install

Tags: javascript

I have tried anyway to reinstall Angular and I can't.

I first had version 9 and uninstalled it:

```
 npm uninstall -g @angular/cli and then npm cache clean --force
```

Once that version was uninstalled I wanted to install version 14 with the following command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@14.0.6
```

but when I check the installed version I get the following error

[image]

Version 9 continues to appear as installed even though I uninstalled it, and the packages below come up with an error, what could it be?

Comment: You uninstalled it globally, but what is listed in your project's `package.json` file?

Comment: I haven't created any project yet

Comment: Try to run `npm cache clean --force` using **administrator** terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular 14 does not install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77826599/angular-14-does-not-install)

Comment: How is this question different than the one from you I saw earlier today? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77826599/angular-14-does-not-install